# Setting default value on sequelize ENUM type

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

I am currently trying to set default value on a column with type `ENUM`, however if i set the `defaultValue` to `"employee"` which is one of the values of the enum, I get the below error message:

```
$ npx sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.0, CLI: 5.5.0, ORM: 5.15.1]

Loaded configuration file "src\config\config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20190824180419-create-user: migrating =======

ERROR: invalid input value for enum "enum_Users_role": "employee"
```

Find bellow my user migration file definition

```
20190824180419-create-user.js


export default {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
    uuid: {
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  role: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 'manager', 'supplier'],
    defaultValue: 'employee'
  }
}),
down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('Users')
```

};

Find bellow my user model file definition:

```
user.js

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 'manager', 'supplier'),
      defaultValue: 'employee'
     }
  }, {});
  User.associate = () => {
   // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

**Package versions:**

```
node: v10.16.0
npm: 6.9.0
sequelize: 5.15.1
sequelize-cli: 5.5.0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are setting [ENUM values](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~ENUM.html) wrong. It should be like you did in model definition via `ENUM` constructor:

```
{
  type: Sequelize.DataTypes.ENUM('employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 'manager', 'supplier'),
  defaultValue: 'employee',
}
```

Comment: I am getting error `SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input value for enum`

Answer (score 2):

Can you remove the `defaultValue` in the model and change the format as @rkm mentioned. So you have something like this:

```
role: DataTypes.ENUM('employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 'manager', 'supplier'),
```

and in your migration file as:

```
role: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 'manager', 'supplier'),
defaultValue: 'employee'
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Having these in your migration file should work

```
role: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM('employee', 'super_admin', 'travel_admin', 'travel_team_manager', 
          'manager', 'supplier'),
    defaultValue: 'employee'
}
```